# Duplication offset ignored in reflections

Tags: path

Good day.

I got a weird problem. Again. I created a tunnel scene where I am using a path to create the lamps inside the tunnel. I am using an offset of 4 to reduce the ammount of lamps on the wall.

But in the reflections (water puddles) on the ground, the offset seems to be ignored. It therefore relects 4x as much light as visible in the scene.

You can see the effct in the attached image.

[image]

Where did I make the mistake?

Comment: Looks ok to me, those are not settings that can be different between direct rays and reflection ones. Are you using lamp objects, besides the modeled meshes on the wall? Those look like point light reflections.

Comment: Your only mistake is your expectations of what will get reflected at certain locations. The reflections under the point of the red arrow are from the farther end of the tunnel as it curves. See how the reflections curve with the tunnel. If you hold a mirror in front of your face and parallel to the floor, you will not see your face, you will see the roof at the far end of the room.

Comment: Yes - the reflections are point lights. I am not done with the scene yet.

I understand. So I will change the angle a bit to get it somehow closer to my expectations.